# Not getting full path from file

Tags: javascript

Hello when ever i try to retrieve the full path of the browsed file by using ***

> request.getParameter()

***only the file name is being returned to the next jsp file.
Can someone help me..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please be a little more specific, and add more relevant code.

Comment: please put more description what you actual needed.

Comment: have you tried with application.getRealPath("folder/filename");

Comment: He is new to Stack Overflow so give advise rather than givin downvote...

Answer (score -1):

When you upload a file you will get only the File Name and not the entire path that you see in the file upload field. This path is of user file system. If you want to save the file, you need to save it in server side directory path.

Comment: It seems the OP is new to SO and I think this is the info he needs. Any reason for the downvote ?